# SQL Find & return matched keywords from list

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

**Scenario**

Say I have a `comments` table like

```
comment_id | comment
1          | a quick fox jumped over the lazy dog 
2          | a lazy bull slept in the chicken den
```

and I have a `keywords` table like this

```
animal_id  | keyword
1          | bull
2          | chicken
3          | dog
4          | fox
```

**Question**

1. Is it possible to do a search comment for the keywords shown? something like `instr(comments.comment, keywords.keyword)`?
2. Is it possible to return the matched keywords from the table like

```
comment_id | animal_id
1          | 3
1          | 4
2          | 1
2          | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If version of sqllite grater than **3.7.x**, you can use **instr** function  as [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/6c110/3). **Instr** function  searches a substring in a string and returns an integer that index of the substring, which is the first character of the substring. You can view http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-instr/

```
select com.comment_id, kword.animal_id 
from comments com
join keywords kword on instr(com.comment, kword.keyword)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables and use the LIKE operator:

```
select
  c.comment_id, k.animal_id
from comments c inner join keywords k
on ' ' || c.comment || ' ' like '% ' || k.keyword || ' %'
```

the concatenation of spaces in both the `comment` and `keyword` is needed to ensure that the `keyword` is not only a part of a word inside the comment.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5Tq9xoGqqVunBhMQM9j8GS/0).
Results:

```
| comment_id | animal_id |
| ---------- | --------- |
| 1          | 3         |
| 1          | 4         |
| 2          | 1         |
| 2          | 2         |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` and `LIKE`:

```
SELECT c.comment_id, k.animal_id FROM comments c
CROSS JOIN keywords k
WHERE c.comment LIKE '%' || k.keyword || '%'
```

[image]

Comment: Why would you do a cross join to return a huge dataset and then filter it?

Comment: I tested it with about 260K records and my solution was better. After that, I tested it with about 1.2 million records and I saw your solution is faster, but no big difference(mine: 97437 ms, yours: 95564 ms).

Comment: A cross join is not better in any case. Also your solution is logically and syntactically wrong.

Comment: If you did make a test you would have already found out that your answer is wrong.

Comment: We are talking about `SQL` and I think my answer is `SQL` syntax. In small data, mine was better and you can test it. See my answer again please, I've sent my result as an image.

Comment: Didn't you see the tag **SQLite**?

Comment: So you think that your code is valid sql? It would run only in SQL Server and then again it would not return the correct results.

Comment: Now, will you undestand that there is a reason that there exist different types of joins and each one has its use? In this case a cross join **should not be used**.